# Is it possible to create multisig wallet from command line?

Tags: electrum

In a situation where electrum script is included in PATH so that `electrum command args...` is possible from terminal command line, is it possible to create multisig wallet in this terminal?

I know that `electrum create -w path/to/wallet` will create wallet in the path `path/to/wallet`.  I'm wondering if it's possible to create multisig wallet from command line also.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely via the CLI. The `create` command can be used to create new wallet and the `restore` command can be used to restore from seed, xprv, xpub, private keys or addresses. Neither supports multisig though.

There is `createmultisig` that lets you create a multisig address from public keys. But it won't create a full fledged wallet.